# How to show that $z + \frac{1}{z}$ maps $\{z=x+iy|y>0\} \cap \{z||z|\leqslant1\}$ onto the lower half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show that $z + \frac{1}{z}$ maps $\{z=x+iy|y>0\} \cap \{z||z|\leqslant 1\}$ onto the lower half plane?

Suppose $y$ belongs to the lower half plane, want to solve $z + \frac{1}{z}=y$. There must be two solutions(counting multiplicity) by fundamental theorem of algebra. But how do I guarantee that one solution must be in $\{z=ix+y|y>0\} \cap \{z||z|=1\}$?

Comment: Are you sure $\cap$ is not $\cup$?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$S:=\{z=x+iy|y>0\} \cap \{z||z|\leq 1\} \\
T= \{w | Im(w) \leq 0 \} \\
f(z) =z+\frac{1}{z}$$

Then 
$$f(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}=z+\frac{\bar{z}}{|z|^2}$$
Since $|z|\leq 1$ we have 
$$
Im(f(z))=y-\frac{y}{|z|^2} \leq 0 \,.
$$

This shows that $f(S) \subset T$.

Next, to prove ONTO.

Let $w \in T$.

If $Im(w)=0$ then look for $z \in S$ of $|z|=1$ such that $f(z)=w$.

Recall that in this case you have
$$f(z)=z+\frac{\bar{z}}{|z|^2}=z+\bar{z}$$

If $Im(z)<0$ then you need
$$z+\frac{\bar{z}}{|z|^2}= w \Rightarrow \\
\bar{z}+\frac{z}{|z|^2}= \bar{w} \\
$$

Try adding and subtracting these two relations to get something about $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I am really really sorry! I keep typing it wrong. But how do you define the square root for complex numbers?

Comment: @Keith The square roots of $\omeg$ are the two roots of $z^2=\omega$. It is easiest to calculate them in polar coordinates.